# Cant restore previous drawings in winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

So I'm trying to make a tetris game but the shapes dont stay.
The first shape works fine but then when the 2nd shapes comes in, the first one disappears.

I tried settings up the whole area in Invalidate() of Form1 like in code but no help.
Even simple Invalidate() wont work.

Any guidance will be a great help.

```
namespace Tetris
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int value = 0;
        Timer timer;
        string s;
        Point p;
        int widthOfShape = 0; int heightOfShape = 0;
        Graphics g;
        Point sizeOfPanel;

        Dictionary<int, string> shapes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            shapes.Add(1, "Rectangle");
            shapes.Add(2, "Square");
            p.X = 0;
            p.Y = 0;
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 800;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
            SomeRandom();
            sizeOfPanel = new Point(488, 337);
        }

        public void SomeRandom()
        {
            s = ChooseOneShape();

            switch (s)
            {
                case "Rectangle":
                    widthOfShape = 80; heightOfShape = 20;
                    this.Invalidate(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 400));
                    break;

                case "Square":
                    widthOfShape = 40; heightOfShape = 40;
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (p.X + widthOfShape < sizeOfPanel.X && p.Y + heightOfShape < sizeOfPanel.Y)
            {
                p.X += 30;
                p.Y += 30;
                this.Invalidate(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 400));
            }
            else {
                p.X = 0;p.Y = 0;s = string.Empty;
                SomeRandom(); }
        }

        public string ChooseOneShape()
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int index = r.Next(1, shapes.Count+1);
            return shapes[index];
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, p.X, p.Y, widthOfShape, heightOfShape);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Loops through your shapes and draw each one every time in the paint event.  You probably need a class to hold more information about each shape and their position, etc.

Comment: __All__ your graphics need to be re-drawn __each__ time the form is Painted, so you will need to store the data..!

Comment: But what if I use a UserControl to draw my shapes. In that case I would need to Invalidate() that UserControl and so there would be no need to store data of the other shapes, right?

Comment: You don't want a control for every shape (makes things more complicated and harder to draw).  Just a class that stores the information and a List of those classes.

Comment: We have lots of questions with answers already which provide great details on the right way to draw graphics using Winforms. The basic conceptual issue you need to grasp is that Winforms graphics are _not_ persistent. Every time the `Paint` method is called, it has to redraw _everything_ (well, you can take the clip area into account and only draw things that are visible if you like), just like the comment from @TaW says. In fact, I'll bet if you look through just their answers, you'll find plenty of Winforms examples to help you. I've seen them answer questions similar to this before.

Answer (score -1):

I modified you code the way I think it should of been done.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tetris
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int X = 488;
        const int Y = 337;
        Graphics g;
        Point sizeOfPanel;
        Timer timer;
        TetrisShape currentShape;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        }
        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new TetrisShape("Rectangle");
            new TetrisShape("Square");
            currentShape = TetrisShape.SomeRandom();
            panel1.Controls.Add(currentShape);
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 800;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Start();
            sizeOfPanel = new Point(X, Y);
            panel1.Height = Y;
            panel1.Width = X;

        }
        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentShape.p.X + currentShape.Width < sizeOfPanel.X && currentShape.p.Y + currentShape.Height < sizeOfPanel.Y)
            {
                currentShape.Top += 30;
                panel1.Refresh();
            }
            else
            {
                currentShape.p = new Point(0, 0);
                currentShape = TetrisShape.SomeRandom();
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, currentShape.ClientRectangle);
        }
    }
    public class TetrisShape : Control
    {
        static Dictionary<int, TetrisShape> shapes = new Dictionary<int, TetrisShape>();
        static Random rand = new Random();
        static string[] shapeTypes = { "Rectangle", "Square" };
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Point p { get; set; }
        public static int maxNumber;

        public TetrisShape(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            p = new Point(0, 0);
            this.BackColor = Color.Red;
            switch (name)
            {
                case "Rectangle":
                    this.Invalidate(new Rectangle());
                    Width = 80; 
                    Height = 20;
                    number = ++maxNumber;
                    shapes.Add(number, this);

                    break;

                case "Square":
                    this.Invalidate(new Rectangle());
                    Width  = 40; 
                    Height = 40;
                    break;
            }
        }
        public static TetrisShape SomeRandom()
        {
            int shapeNumber = rand.Next(TetrisShape.shapeTypes.Length);
            return new TetrisShape(TetrisShape.shapeTypes[shapeNumber]);
        }
        public TetrisShape ChooseOneShape()
        {
            int index = rand.Next(1, shapes.Count + 1);
            return shapes[index];
        }
    }
}
```